# ABI is incomplete for contract written in "Solidity Multiple files format", e.g. 0xedfcb78e73f7ba6ad2d829bf5d462a0924da28ed

Tags: solidity, abi, bscscan

For this contract https://bscscan.com/address/0xedfcb78e73f7ba6ad2d829bf5d462a0924da28ed#code
There are eight source files which are known as "Solidity Multiple files format"

However neither the bscscan website:
https://bscscan.com/address/0xedfcb78e73f7ba6ad2d829bf5d462a0924da28ed#code
nor the bscscan API:
https://api.bscscan.com/api?module=contract&action=getabi&address=0xedfcb78e73f7ba6ad2d829bf5d462a0924da28ed
can get full ABI.

They only provide the ABI for the first source file.

How do I get the full and functional ABI to interact with?

Answer (score 1):

> *They only provide the ABI for the first source file.*

That's an expected result. The ABI JSON is generated only for `public` and `external` functions, as well as for autogenerated functions from `public` properties **of the main contract and its parents**.

The imported contracts are usually called from or inherited by the main contract, but theoretically they can be unused as well.

*Note: It doesn't need to be the first contract in the order, you pass the main contract name as one of the options for compilation.*

---

In your example, the `AdminUpgradeabilityProxy` is the main contract, deriving from `UpgradeabilityProxy`, which derives from `Proxy`. So the ABI json contains all `public` and `external` functions and events from these three contracts.